# OCI Runtime error when using chown command. Failed to create shim task

Tags: angular, docker, cicd

I am an absolute beginner with anything devops and somehow managed to find myself in the position to need to work with it.

I have the following error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sznJK.png

failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed:unable to start container process: can't get final child's PID from pipe; EOF: unknown

The command on docker that seems to cause it is

```
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache.nginx &&  chown -R nginx:nginx /var.log/nginx &&  chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going on, and I am sorry if the question lacks details, again, I am a complete Docker Noob.
This is also what bad management looks like

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

> /var.log/nginx

Maby it should be:

> /var/log/nginx

also same for:

> var/cache.nginx